# sitemap not generated properly in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

I am trying to generate google sitemap using Magento default functionality. It goes to infinity after some urls. I have 13000+ products in my store. My CMS and category sitemap generated but when start to product its goes to infinity.

Can anyone please help me what is the problem with my store.

Comment: Hi, You can create and generate site map from admin panel.